# Flutter error when build on real device (build flutter demo application)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I just create an app from flutter with demo application, I didn't add anything, just run

**1**

```
flutter create app_test_001
```

**2**

```
flutter create .
```

**3**

```
flutter build ios --release
```

When I run the emulator, it shows the default simple application
and when I run it on my iphone it gets the white screen

**Result on emulador**
[image: result emulator]

**Result in real device**

[image]

Comment: The problem with this question is it doesn't include any details, so we are as clueless as you are.

Comment: it's just a standard application that I create to build, it didn't have any different code

Comment: Please attach `flutter log` output and also build/install log

Comment: I have this problem too, really weird. Only on release version. Tried it on an iPhone 8 and 13 Pro.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Make sure everything is right `flutter doctor`
2. Restart your computer
3. Check if your mobile device is updated

Also, these issues can relate: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18409